# What exactly is remarkable about Proto-Germanic *wrakjon?

Tags: etymology, proto-germanic

> [wretch, n. and adj.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/230654?rskey=n792MY&result=1#eid)
>   Etymology:  Old English wrecca , wræcca , = Old Saxon wrekkio , -eo (applied to the Magi), Old High German reccheo , reccho , etc., exile, adventurer, knight errant (Middle High German and German recke warrior, hero)
>   < Old Germanic *wrakja(n)- ,
>   < the stem wrak- , wrek- : see [wreak v](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/230577#eid13944131). The contrast in the development of the meaning in English and German is remarkable.
>
> [[Etymonline:]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=wretch&searchmode=none) Old English wrecca "wretch, stranger, exile,"
>    from Proto-Germanic *** *wrakjon* "pursuer; one pursued"** (cognates: Old Saxon wrekkio, Old High German reckeo "a banished person, exile," German recke "renowned warrior, hero") [...]

Would someone please explain OED`s last sentence? What's remarkable?

From the above, I see that *** *wrakjon*** induced two cognates with opposing meanings (in English, the pursued; in German, the pursuer). Is this  difference what is  remarkable?

Instead, should the remark arise from the Proto-Germanic ***wrakjon**? Was this a contronym?
How can the same word mean the subject and the object (ie: **"pursuer; one pursued"**)?

Comment: The opposing cognates is the remarkable part. The -jan/-jon suffix is the PIE causative suffix, which later palatalized final consonants (_wreak/wretch_, but also _milk/milch, drink/drench, break/breach, blank/blanch, bank/bench, hang/hinge,_ and many more pairs. As for how they got different, it's a matter of whose side you're on. If the knights are chasing you, you're a wretch; but if you're a knight chasing a fugitive, you're wreaking justice.

Comment: When was that entry written? I ask because I suspect that 'remarkable' is used there in its (now somewhat archaic) sense of 'noteworthy', rather than the modern sense of 'extraordinary'.

Comment: *Recke* certainly has to be compared to *rect-* et al, *Wrack* to *verrecken*.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are right about the reason for the term "remarkable": because the English term (*wretch*) is pejorative, whereas German *Recke* refers to a figure (a warrior or hero) that is likely to be praised.

Whether this contrast is objectively remarkable -- i.e. whether such a semantic development is improbable or statistically rare -- is a different question. But, I doubt that the person who made that statement (in the dictionary entry) was trying to be objectively precise.